# Excel complicated formula for a user form

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, vlookup

Some of my colleagues attend conferences, meetings and workshops in various cities. 
An example of a made up itinerary is shown below

[image]

The itinerary includes stopovers and each location is marked by a trip number. (A:15 to A:22) 
I am working on a user form which would give me the time spent in hours and minutes from the departure to the arrival time for each trip number. Note that some trips include a stopover which is why there are three trip number entries for number 1 (trip to Frankfurt via Paris) 
I know that the overall time spent for all these trips is 185 hours and 45 minutes as stated in L:23.
In red, along raw 23 there are five formulas as follows:

C:23 shows 24/06/2016 which is `=C17`

D:23 shows 19:15 which is `=D17`

H:23 shows 16/01/2016 which is `=LOOKUP(2,1/(H17:H22<>""),H17:H22)` it picks up the last date inserted between H17:H22

J:23 shows 13:00 which is `=LOOKUP(2,1/(J17:J22<>""),J17:J22)` it picks up the last time value inserted between J17:J22

L:23 shows 185:45 hours and minutes. It is the difference between the departure date and time of the first and the arrival date and time of the last trip. (Overall time in hours and minutes) `=MAX(0,(H23+J23)-(C23+D23))`

I need a way to work out the total time of 185:45 broken down between various business trip numbers in C:26 to C:29. Note that trips will always be shown in a logical order i.e. 1,2,3 but the amount of legs per trip will vary depending on stop overs. The minimum amount of trips is 1 and the maximum amount of trips is 4.

Thanking you in advance
Abe

Comment: I noticed that you tried to add to the question by editing my answer.  It has been rejected by the community.  Please post a new question, in its own post.  Trying to post it here will not get the attention a new question deserves.

Comment: If the answers I gave you worked then please mark them as correct, by hitting the green check mark by the answer it is something only the questioner can do.  see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hello @ScottCraner I was away for a couple of days once my late reply. I have marked this one and the other you helped on. They will show once my reputation has increased slightly. Thank you for your help. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: You do not need rep points to mark as correct.  At the side of each answer is a grey green check mark that only you can see and click.  When you click it it becomes solid green.  This is how you indicate that the answer is the correct one.  To up vote you must have a certain number of rep points but not to click the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXT(MAX(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26,$I$17:$I$22+$J$17:$J$22))-MIN(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26,$C$17:$C$22+$D$17:$D$22)),"[hh]:mm")
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Put in C26, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter then copy down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Edit:  As per OP's comments, what was wanted was the total of time from beginning of leg to the beginning of the next leg.  So the formula was changed to:

```
=IF(MIN(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26+1,$C$17:$C$22+$D$17:$D$22))=0,MAX(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26,$I$17:$I$22+$J$17:$J$22)),MIN(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26+1,$C$17:$C$22+$D$17:$D$22)))-MIN(IF($A$17:$A$22=A26,$C$17:$C$22+$D$17:$D$22))
```

This is still an array formula. It needs to be confirmed by hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copied down.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you Scott but it does not seem to work for me, I get an #VALUE! error message. I am not sure what I am doing wrong..

Comment: The formula works but the result does not seem to match with mine (total in 185:45. So I am going to review it all and see. many thanks for your help, brilliant!

Comment: This way does not work if we are looking at more than one trip. On your example above, trip 2 should start at the same time trip 1 ends. To number them 1,2,3... might not be the best way. :(

Comment: @Abigal I did not realize you wanted the end of leg 1 to be the beginning of leg 2.  I can fix it but I just got up and have meetings this morning.  I will fix it in about 3 hours. It is not a hard fix.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will wait very patiently for your additional help. Appreciated!

Comment: That's great. Thank you ever so much @ScottCraner. I have to post another one tomorrow, I will tag you in case you can help. it is very similar to this one with a little twist. thank again

Comment: @Abigal Please consider marking as correct, by hitting the green check mark by the answer.